# How connect of vb6 to postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, vb6

How to connect VB6 to Postgresql database ? Is there anyone out there can help me out of this ?Please help. Thaanks a Lot .

Comment: There's an ADO.NET provider for Postgresql. It won't work with VB 6, though. Do you really have to use VB 6? Isn't VB.NET an option?

Comment: @zmbq Yeah. It's acceptable to use VB.net but my machine runs slowly. So i have to use vb6.

Comment: VB6 works fine, lasts a long time.  Ignore the FUD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referencing ADO 2.8:

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection 
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection 
cn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};SERVER=ServerName;port=5432;DATABASE=Database;UID=userID;PWD=password"
'// You'll have to substitute "ServerName", "Database", "userID", and "password" 
cn.ConnectionTimeout = 10 
cn.Open
```

Comment: You might also take a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmpostgresqlole/ which is less indirect than thunking through the ODBC Provider.  There are also for-pay alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [PostgreSQL ODBC driver](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/)?